# Defining \maketitle in a ConTeXt-oriented way

Tags: titles, context

I went on the [wiki page for defining titles in ConTeXt](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Document_Titles), and I already have a "LaTeX-like" solution working (paragraph "In ConTeXt: A more reusable solution"). However, I also read the paragraph "In ConTeXt: A more advanced solution", and I would like to switch to this. The problem is that I can't define new keys in the systemvariable `dt` : I thought I just had to declare it in `\setuptitle`, but it doesn't compile.

Below is a MWE taken from the wiki and just modified to show where the compilation error occurs :

```
\definesystemvariable {dt} % DocumentTitle

\def\setuptitle{\dodoubleempty\dosetuptitle}

\def\dosetuptitle[#1][#2]%
  {\ifsecondargument
     \dodosetuptitle[#1][#2]%
   \else
     \dodosetuptitle[\v!content][#1]%
   \fi}

\def\dodosetuptitle[#1][#2]%
  {\def\dododosetuptitle##1%
    {\getparameters[\??dt##1][#2]}%
    \processcommalist[#1]\dododosetuptitle
  }
% Here is where we define the key-value pairs
\setuptitle
  [\c!title=,
    \c!author=,
    \c!date=\currentdate,
    \c!schoolyear=,  % Undefined control sequence occurs here
  ]
% trying to use the variables...
\protect
```

I tried to look up many pages in the wiki, but it is very hard for me to understand the pages (I don't know anything in low-level TeX). For example, I can't understant at all :

- what is the `\??dt##1` variable ?
- what is the difference between `\definesystemvariable` and `\definedataset` ([this page](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/definedataset)) ?
- which one is best to use in my case ?
- Bonus question : is there a way to define one of the parameters (for instance `\@@dtcontenttitle`) as a marking while processing the coma-separated list ?

I'm sorry if any part of the question is not relevant, as I said I'm a complete ignorant in low-level TeX so I don't really understand what I am doing...

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do something like this:

```
\starttext

\setvariables
   [content]
   [title={Such, Such Were the Joys},
    author=George Orwell,
    date=1948,
    age=8|--|13,
    years=1911|--|1916]

\midaligned{\tfc\getvariable{content}{title}}
\blank[big]
\midaligned{\tfa by \getvariable{content}{author}}
\blank[big]

The essay describes his experience during the years \getvariable{content}{years}, when he was \getvariable{content}{age}. It was first published in \getvariable{content}{date}.

\stoptext
```

Feel free to update the wiki.

[image: such, such were the joys]

Comment: This is perfect, it works wonders and is very simple to use. I will suggest a newer version for the wiki